# Why are my numbers not converting to Boolean?

Tags: javascript, arrays, casting, boolean

so I'm solving this task where I need to return the given array after casting all numbers in it to Boolean and all strings to numbers.

My current code looks like this:

```
const arr = [0, "2", 3, 4, "s"];

function castArr(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(elem) {
    if (typeof elem === Number) {
      return !!elem;
  } else {
     return Number(elem)
  }
  })  
}
```

I have tried also using

```
if (typeof elem === Number) {
      return Boolean(elem)
```

but it still won't convert - in the result I have the same numbers (0, 3, 4).

Can you help me find the mistake here? I'm sure it's not hard, but I am kinda lost...

Comment: `typeof elem === 'Number'`?

Comment: Try using toString(2) to convert to bool and parseInt for number?

Comment: @ITgoldman is right, the problem was in syntax... thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do changes as follows then it will work

```js
const arr = [0, "2", 3, 4, "s"];

function castArr(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(elem) {
    if (typeof elem === 'number') {
      return Boolean(elem);
  } else {
     return Number(elem)
  }
  })  
}
console.log(castArr(arr))
```

Comment: Thanks! Just as I said, the mistake was stupid and obvious....thank you!